# For what values of $n$ does $Q_n$ have a Hamiltonian circuit?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

For $Q_0$, there is a HC. For $Q_1$, there's no HC. For $Q_2$, it forms $C_4$ so there's a HC. After this, I try to reason using Dirac's theorem of sufficiency for HC,

*An n-vertex graph in which each vertex has degree at least $n/2$ must have a Hamiltonian cycle.*

For the cube graph, each vertex has degree of $n$, and the number of vertices is $2^n$, so I realise I can't apply that. Neither can I apply Ore's theorem.

Is there a way to find the answer?

Comment: You can just construct a Hamiltonian cycle recursively for $n\ge2.$ More generally, if $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle, so does the Cartesian product $G\square K_2.$ By the way, $Q_0$ does *not* have a Hamiltonian cycle. (How many vertices does $Q_0$ have? What do you think is the length of its Hamiltonian cycle?)

Comment: I thought $Q0$ has a single vertex and so it is considered to be a hamiltonian circuit of length 0? I did have a confusion regarding this. @bof

Comment: I think a cycle of length $n$ is a connected $2$-regular graph with $n$ vertices and $n$ edges. A graph consisting of a single vertex **with a loop** has a Hamiltonian cycle (of length one). A graph consisting of two vertices joined by two edges has a Hamiltonian cycle of length two. A **simple** graph with a Hamiltonian cycle must have at least $3$ vertices. Not everybody agrees with this.

Comment: Hypercube Qn is regular simple graph with n vertices where degree of each vertex in n . So min degree of each vertex is greater than n/2. Now apply Dirac's Theorem to conclude it is Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably by induction.
You already proved the base case for $n = 2$.

Now, suppose $Q_{k}$ has a Hamiltonian circuit $C$. We can construct $Q_{k+1}$ from taking two copies of $Q_{k}$, then adding $0$ to the end of the vertex bit-strings in one copy of $Q_{k}$, and adding $1$ in the other (to see this more easily, try drawing $Q_{3}$ from 2 copies of $Q_{2}$).

In the first copy, take the Hamiltonian circuit $C$, and delete the final edge to form a Hamiltonian path $H$ and label the start/end vertices $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$. Then, join $v_{2}$ to $w_{2}$, the corresponding vertex in the second copy of $Q_{k}$, and reverse the path $H$ to get a another Hamiltonian path in the second copy of $Q_{k}$ that ends at $w_{1}$. As $w_{1}$ is adjacent to $v_{1}$, join these two vertices with a final edge that thus completes the Hamiltonian circuit.
Hence, $Q_{k+1}$ has a Hamiltonian circuit whenever $Q_{k}$ does, so by induction $Q_{n}$ has a Hamiltonian circuit for all $n\geq2$.